# Changing selects to inputs - going back and forth

Tags: jquery

I am going back and forth between a SELECT and a textbox for the state field based on what country is selected from the country SELECT on my form.  The first time the country is changed off of US or Canada I have functionality.  However,  when the country is switched back to US or Canada it does not revert back to the select.  Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#country").on('change', function() {
        var countrySelect = $("#country").val(); 

        if(!(countrySelect == "CA" || countrySelect =="US")){
            //$("#state").replaceWith($("#state").clone().attr('type', 'text'));
            $("#state").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="state" id="state">');
        }
    });


});
```

Thank you

Comment: but where in your code it is supposed to reverse back?

Comment: Yeah, you don't even tell it to revert back. You need an else clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just posted an answer that I'm going to edit with the following:

The function is $("#country").on("change".....

Are you replacing the id="country" element with the id="state" element?  Because if you are, then this function is never going to be called again.

And in light of mickylaaaad's comment, I'll leave my original answer as well.

```
if(!(countrySelect == "CA" || countrySelect =="US")){
        $("#state").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="state" id="state" />');
    } else {
  $("#state").replaceWith('<select><option ...etc');
 }
```

Comment: I was about to vote you up, before the retraction. I think you were safe in your original assumption.

Comment: I would suggest just hiding/showing two distinct elements rather than replacing it with a new element each time too :)

Comment: @mickylaaad Definitely agreed.  which can easily be done in jquery with `$('#state1').hide(); $('#state2').show();`, or something along those lines.